# font color not working for Apex renderas PDF page

Tags: apex, pdf, html, visualforce, renderas

I have below code where I need a rectangular box with text in white inside it. Box shows fine but text fails to read color #FFFFFF. Can someone please help?

```
<div id="rectangle" style="width:1300px; height:50px; background-color:black" >  <center><font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">  <br> ATTENTION PRACTITIONER : PLEASE FILL IN ALL BLANK FIELDS TO ENSURE TIMELY DELIVERY </br> </font></center></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your css style inside the style tag which is wrapped inside an HTML tag, and also make sure your "applyBodyTag="false"" is set in your apex:page.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf"  applyBodyTag="false" >
    <head>
        <style>
            .tempName{ color: red; } 

        </style>
    </head>
  <div id="rectangle" style="width:1300px; height:50px; background-color:black" >  <center class="tempName"><font size="4" >  <br> ATTENTION PRACTITIONER : PLEASE FILL IN ALL BLANK FIELDS TO ENSURE TIMELY DELIVERY </br> </font></center></div>
</apex:page>
```